# I'm stuck. Help (I don't know what happened)

Tags: camera

I was modelling for an hour, then this happened. I saved, closed it and came back but the same thing was still there.... he[image]lp....

Comment: Its sort of stuck seeing a narrow view of everything, which is a character model.

Comment: Thankfully i fixed it by switching to a different tab... apparently I was modelling in the sculpting tab... oh well. In case anyone has the same issue, just switch tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch tabs. You guys should be good.